# Calculating the time complexity of recursive algorithm T(n) = T(k) + T(n-k)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I want to calculate the time complexity of the following recursive algorithm, where,

```
n = j - i (size of array)
i ≤ k ≤ j
process(A, i, j) takes Θ(n) time 

Algo(Array A[], int i, int j)
    if (i<j)
        k = process(A, i, j)
        Algo(A, i, k)
        Algo(A, k+1, j)
```

I came up with the following:

```
T(n) = Θ(n) + T(k) + T(n-k)
```

I'm not sure if that is correct and if it is, how to proceed from that?

**Update:**

Is the following correct?

The worst case value for k is i or j,

```
T(n) = Θ(n) + T(0) + T(n)
```

Comment: This should rather be posted on https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This should take `O(nlogn)`, it looks similar to merge sort

Comment: @Oswald in merge sort, k = n/2, but here it can be any number between i and j. Will that affect the solution?

Comment: It depends on what *k* is.  Worst case will be *k = i* or *k = j*, in which case this will be O(n*n)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/76325/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/44361403/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.   @adjan, in the future, if you're going to suggest another site, it would help to let the person know not to cross-post (you can suggest they delete the copy here before posting elsewhere).  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This recursive structure is more like quick sort whose worst-case running time  is `O(n^2)`.

```
algorithm quicksort(A, lo, hi) is
    if lo < hi then
        p := partition(A, lo, hi)
        quicksort(A, lo, p – 1)
        quicksort(A, p + 1, hi)
```

The partition algorithm takes `O(N)` time. For analysis please refer [Quick-Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). I can't explain any better.